# c3p0: detecting db down / up events

Tags: java, mysql, c3p0

After reinventing several times the wheel implementing myself db connection pools I have finally decided to give c3p0 a try. It seems to be easy to use and configure once you go through the documentation.

One thing I could not find in the documentation is how to detect, via listener or other mechanism, whenever the db is down or up using c3p0. In our application I need to tell the client the db is down, so it cannot send certain orders that need to be logged in the db. I am wondering if there's a standard way to detect these changes using c3p0 or I have to implement myself an external thread that queries the db periodically by executing a simple select statement.

I feel that this feature is a must in a connection pool and there must be a way to do so using c3p0 but I just can't find it. If this doesn't exists I feel like reinventing the wheel again.

Comment: You should give [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) a try too.

Comment: It has no javadoc or API documentation, or at least I cannot find it. It doesn't look serious to me.

Comment: Its a maven project. It will create the docs when it is build ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connection pool has no way of knowing what the state of the DB or even its connections are until some operation is performed on them. At least some connection pools can be configured to re-create a connection after a certain time, so the pool would at that point notice that there's something wrong. There are also other mechanisms such as a test query that will be executed before the connection is given out, to verify that the connection is valid.

If you want to keep track of the status, you have no option than to poll the DB yourself.

Comment: Hmm... It would be a nice feature to have. A listener that indicates you if the db is up or down. If the db is down, IMO, it is better to queue up the db requests and execute them when you know the db is up and not trying to execute them to catch the exception and retrying the execution again and again.

Comment: That's what monitoring systems are for. They poll different servers to see if they're functioning correctly. It's also definitely not a good idea to queue up request and execute them once the DB is up again. While that may work in very simple cases, it would mess up transactions and corrupt data in real world situations.

Comment: I receive some data measurements from a devide and they must be all stored in the historical db. No measure can be lost if the application has received it. The only way to do this is by queuing up the inserts while the db is down and executing them when the db is up again. Please tell me if you can think of a better way.

Comment: I just said that it would work in simple cases, such as yours. It wouldn't work in a highly concurrent multi transaction situation. Therefore it's not a general solution.